# Leer excel con Apache POI en java por nombre de columna

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Buena tarde expertos, tengo una problemática con un proyecto que consiste en leer un archivo de excel y validar por columnas los datos de los mismos, he logrado leer el archivo sin problemas y las validaciones también (mediante expresiones regulares) mediante la librería Apache POI el detalle es que sólo puedo leer columnas por índice de columna (ejemplo índice 0 = columna 1, índice 1 = columna 2 etc) con el método `getColumnIndex()` el problema es que necesito leerlas por su nombre de columna en lugar de por su índice dado que el archivo a leer tenderá a  cambiar de posición las columnas, hay algún método para resolver esto, he probado con:

```
columnIndex = cell.getSheet().getRow(rowIndex).getCell(0).getRichStringCellValue().toString();
```

Pero sólo consigo leer toda la fila mas no todas las columnas y filas.

Adjunto el código que utilizo para leer los archivos:

```
 Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("C:\\archivo.xlsx"));

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    System.out.println("Número total de filas: " + totalRows);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        rowIndex = row.getRowNum();

        int rowIndex2 = rowIndex +1;

        if (rowIndex2 < 8) {
            continue;
        }
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

            cell = cellIterator.next();
            columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();


            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    columnName = "columna 1";
                    //System.out.println(columnName+" -> " + rowIndex);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    columnName = "Columna 2";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    columnName = "Columna 3";
                    break;

            }


            value = this.getValue(cell);
            valid = this.isValid(columnIndex, value);

            if (valid && (value != "")) {
                continue;
            }


            if (value!="")
            {
            System.out.print("Valorno válido: " + columnName + " - " + rowIndex2);
            System.out.println(" -> valor no válido: " + value);
            }

        }

    }

    return procesarBTR();
}

private String getValue(Cell cell) {
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            // return columnName;
            return "";

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
             return "CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN";
           // return cell.getStringCellValue();

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            return "CELL_TYPE_ERROR";

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:

            /*switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    return cell.getStringCellValue();
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    return cell.getNumericCellValue() + "";
                default:
                    return "";}*/
            return cell.getStringCellValue();


        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            return fmt.formatCellValue(cell);

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            return cell.getStringCellValue();

        default:
            return "valor desconocido";

    }

}
```

Código que realiza validaciones
.
.
.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices que debes leer las columnas por su nombre? ¿Algo así como columna A, B, D (porque la columna C no necesitas leerla, etcétera?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta ,por ejemplo columna 1 se llama "producto" y  tiene el index 0 el getColumnIndex() si lo leo por el index con un ciclo lo lee sin problema pero si lo quiero leer por "producto" (nombre de columna) no encuentro forma de hacerlo

Comment: Bueno, en Excel no puedes nombrar a una columna, no existe ese concepto. Por ende, no habrá manera en otras herramientas de leer columnas por su "nombre". POI trabaja leyendo filas mediante la clase `Row` y las celdas que hay en esa fila mediante la clase `Cell`. Según lo que me comentas, tu mejor opción sería posicionarte en la fila que tendrá los nombres, leer todas las celdas para capturar los nombres y almacenar una especie de metadata de tus datos en el excel, que sería 1) Nombre de Columna 2) Número de Celda en la fila. Con esa metadata parsear el resto de datos en el Excel.

Comment: Si la posición donde están los nombres en mi archivo sería la fila 7 en esa fila están lo que sería mis nombres de columna lo puedo  obtener con row pero de verdad no tengo idea de como hacer lo que me dices, podrías ayudarme?? muchas gracias

Comment: Disculpa la demora, pero ya publiqué una respuesta. Espero que aún te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como mencioné en comentarios (adaptado):

En Excel no puedes nombrar a una columna, no existe ese concepto. Por ende, no habrá manera en otras herramientas de leer columnas por su "nombre". POI trabaja leyendo filas mediante la clase `Row` y las celdas que hay en esa fila mediante la clase `Cell`. Según lo que me comentas, tu mejor opción sería:

1. Declarar un mapa que sirva como metadata de nombre de columna y ubicación (número) de columna.
2. En tu archivo Excel y hoja a analizar, posicionarte en la fila que tendrá los nombres de las columnas.
3. Para cada celda de dicha fila:

   3.1. Si la celda posee texto y no está vacía, almacenar una nueva entrada en el mapa. La entrada consiste en el valor de texto de la celda como llave y el número de columna como valor.
4. Una vez analizada la metadata de tu archivo, parsear el resto de datos en el Excel utilizando solo las columnas que deseas leer. Para ello, te apoyas en el mapa de metadata. Para esta parte, se asume que debes tener una colección o estructura donde estén los "nombres de las columnas" que vas a procesar.

Se provee un ejemplo del algoritmo descrito arriba (IMPORTANTE: se asume que las celdas no están combinadas y que solo hay 1 sola fila para los nombres de las columnas)

```
//paso 0. Definir una colección con nombres de las columnas a procesar
//considera que esto lo puedes leer de un archivo de configuración,
//input de usuario o cualquier otra fuente
List<String> columnas = Arrays.asList("Apellido", "Prima");
//paso 1.
Map<String, Integer> mapNombresColumnas = new HashMap<>();
//paso 2.
//número de fila donde están los nombres de celda
//recuerda que POI está basado con índice 0
//si tus nombres están en la fila 1, entonces deberías iniciar esta
//variable con 0.
final int filaNombresColumnas = ...;
//ubicación del archivo Excel a procesar
File archivoExcel = new File("/ruta/de/archivo/excel.xlsx");
//abrir el archivo con POI
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(archivoExcel);
//ubicarse en la hoja donde vas a procesar
//si es la primera hoja, debes indicar 0
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(...);
//acceder a la fila con los nombres de las columnas
Row filaNombresColumna = sheet.getRow(filaNombresColumnas);
//paso 3.
//utilizando el poder de Java 8
row.cellIterator().forEachRemaining(cell -> {
    //paso 3.1.
    String valorCelda = cell.getStringCellValue().trim();
    if (!valorCelda.isEmpty()) {
        mapNombresColumnas.put(valorCelda, cell.getColumnIndex());
    }
});
//paso 4.
//se asume que los valores para procesar se encuentran en la fila
//siguiente a la fila donde están los nombres de las columnas
int indiceDatos = filaNombresColumnas + 1;
Row filaDatos = null;
//recorrer todas las filas con datos
while ((filaDatos = sheet.getRow(indiceDatos++)) != null) {
    //se procesan solo las celdas en base a los "nombres" de esas columnas
    for (String col : columnas) {
       //el resultado de mapNombresColumnas.get(col) es
       //el número de columna a leer
       //en este caso, solo se imprime el resultado
       //puedes reemplazar esto por la manera en que debas procesar la información
       System.out.print(filaDatos.getCell(mapNombresColumnas.get(col)) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Para un archivo Excel donde la primera hoja tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
        A           B         C      D
1    Nombre   | Apellido  | Edad | Prima
2    Luis     | Hernández |   28 | 150.43
3    José     | Zavala    |   35 | 170.21
4    Mercedes | Velásquez |   17 | 112.86
```

Y utilizando:

```
final int filaNombresColumnas = 0;
//...
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Se obtiene el siguiente resultado:

```
Hernández 150.43 
Zavala 170.21 
Velásquez 112.86
```